# how to merge or join data frame and keep the row names as well?

Tags: r

I have few data frame , one column is values and their corresponding names. 
I want when I merge them I keep the row names there too

for example

```
df1<- data.frame(replicate(1,sample(0:1,10,rep=TRUE)))
df2<- data.frame(replicate(1,sample(0:1,10,rep=TRUE)))
df3<- data.frame(replicate(1,sample(0:1,10,rep=TRUE)))
```

I expect to have an output like

```
row.names1  variable    row.names2  variable    row.names2  variable
1              1            1           1           1           0
2              1            2           0           2           1
3              0            3           0           3           1
4              0            4           1           4           1
5              0            5           0           5           0
6              0            6           0           6           0
7              0            7           1           7           0
8              0            8           1           8           0
9              0            9           0           9           0
10             1            10          1          10           1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want to `cbind` the datasets keeping the rownames.  An option using `data.table` is

```
library(data.table) #data.table_1.9.5
dt <- do.call(cbind,lapply(mget(paste0("df",1:3)),
           as.data.table, keep.rownames=TRUE))
setnames(dt, seq(2,ncol(dt),by=2), rep('variable',3))
setnames(dt, seq(1,ncol(dt), by=2), paste0('row.names', 1:(ncol(dt)/2)))
head(dt,2)
#   row.names1 variable row.names2 variable row.names3 variable
#1:          1        0          1        1          1        1
#2:          2        0          2        1          2        0
```

Comment: this is cool but it works when the name of three data frame is df1 to df3, what if the names are different ?

Comment: @Yoingchin How many datasets you have.? If you have say 3 datasets, `abc`, `xyz`, `def`, then `do.call(cbind, lapply(list(abc, xyz, def), as.data.table, keep. rownames=TRUE))`

Comment: @Yoingchin Best option would to read the data from files into a list, i.e. `files <- list.files()` assuming that only those files are in the working directory. `lst <- lapply(files, read.table, header=TRUE); do.call(cbind, lapply(lst, as.data.table, keep.rownames=TRUE))` or use `fread`

Comment: I removed all other files from the working directory and kept only those files  then I wrote files <- ... which was ok but when I wrote lst <--- I got an error like Error in make.names(col.names, unique = TRUE) : 
  invalid multibyte string at '<89>PNG'
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In FUN(c("a_total_view.png", "Case1.R", "genset.txt", "GS-P-R",  :
  line 3 appears to contain embedded nulls
2: In FUN(c("a_total_view.png", "Case1.R", "genset.txt", "GS-P-R",  :
  line 4 appears to contain embedded nulls

Comment: @Yoingchin When you read the files individually, you didn't have problem?  Also, in the warning message, it seems like there is `.png` file as well.

Comment: I found the mistake ! thanks now works fine and I accepted your solution

Answer (score 1):

```
do.call(cbind,mget(paste0("df",1:3)))
```

Comment: But the OP also want the rownames columns (as per the expected result)

Comment: @Metrics this is cool but it works when the name of three data frame is df1 to df3, what if the names are different ?

Comment: You can enter all the names of dataframe as the list  e.g.,`do.call(cbind,list(mtcars,mtcars))`.